# Keep Talking and Nobody Explodes tag

Tags: discussion, tags

We have at least one question about [Keep Talking and Nobody Explodes](http://www.keeptalkinggame.com/) but it's too long for the tag keep-talking-and-nobody-explodes or even keep-talking-nobody-explodes.

Any ideas? I'm leaning towards keep-talking because I can't see any better abbreviations.

Comment: [tag:keep-talking-game] is the domain name of the official game, and might work better for SEO purpose because *Keep Talking* is a Pink Floyd song

Comment: @PrivatePansy Works for me. Perhaps this should be an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The tag name is now [keep-talking-and-nobody-explodes](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/keep-talking-and-nobody-explodes).**

Since the tag length was [increased to 35 characters](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12497/181240), I've went ahead and retagged three questions with the full title.

Answer (score 41):

The game's official site is at http://www.keeptalkinggame.com/, so I suggest [keep-talking-game](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/keep-talking-game). The 'game' part may seem redundant, but it's useful for search engines because there's a Pink Floyd song called Keep Talking